# Cycles Render grainy despite many samples?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So I'm pretty new to the cycles rendering engine, but decided to give it a shot. However the image seems to come out rather grainy whatever I do.

I've tried with up to 700 samples, which already seem like waaay too many, but with no effect.

Any help would meen a lot!  [image: Render of the scene]

The Blender file can be downloaded [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXA7CQuMtyibjBxYkZJbVg5N1k/view)

Comment: 3000 is minimum I would render a glossy scene. Usually you need like 5k samples. 700 is very low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check "Square Samples", otherwise Blender will use -exactly- the number of AA samples as you type in. 700 unsquare AA samples is around 27 square samples.

The blend file you provided has it set at 100 AA samples, which is barely preview quality.

Additionally, you have some REALLY strange material shaders. Theres a fresnel node plugged directly into a color node. A ray path node directly in an add shader node. You mix glossy and glass shaders.
Its really strange, i've never seen shader setups like this.

Last thing: you built a closed box and put objects inside with indirect light, this gives you huge amounts of bounce light, which creates loads of noise. If you get a HDR instead you can get better results with way less bounce and noise than this approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! I've just been grabbing from different tutorials, so maybe that's why the shaders have turned out so weird...

Anyway, how do I get ahold of HDR? or can I even make one myself?

Comment: @philipdamore This is a good website for it: https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/